# Lisp: reading file containing url

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm new to Lisp and have a quite basic question.

I'm working with a list containing lists.

```
(defvar *stationen* nil)

(defun make-station (name uri)
  (list :name name :uri uri))

(defun save-db ()
  (with-open-file (out "list.txt"
                       :direction :output
                       :if-exists :supersede)
    (with-standard-io-syntax
      (princ *stationen* out))))

(defun load-db ()
  (with-open-file (in "list.txt")
    (with-standard-io-syntax
      (setf *stationen* (READ in)))))

(load-db)
```

The data contains an uri `http://www....`. Well, I get the following error, when I try to read that list:

```
The name "HTTP" does not designate any package.
[Condition of type SB-KERNEL:SIMPLE-PACKAGE-ERROR]
```

I can guess why this happens (Lisp is trying to interpret "http" as a package, right?). But how can I save my uri to the file and read it again, without Lisp throwing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatives:

1. Just write it as a string.
2. use READ-CHAR, READ-LINE or READ-SEQUENCE
3. advanced: write and read using a custom reader macro

Btw., please post formatted Lisp code.

Comment: thanks a lot! (this is my first post, i was glad i figured out how to post code at all; seems a bit odd and not very practical compared to posting code on other sides)

Comment: @user2080255: yes, I use an editor to shift code to the right. Select some text and then type 'c-u 4 c-x TAB' in Emacs. Use -4 instead of 4 to shift back.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use PRINT instead of PRINC to write out the URL.